# Russian texts change to question marks

Tags: pdftex, cyrillic, russian

I wrote in this structure:

```
\documentclass[10 pt]{book}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont,setspace,hyperref,amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,color,multirow,graphicx,subfigure, color }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,latexsym,amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\textwidth 170mm \textheight 240mm
\topmargin -9mm
\oddsidemargin -5mm
\evensidemargin -5mm

\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{l}
{\sf Bulletin of the Institute of Mathematics}\\
{\sf  20**,\No *, pp.\pageref{firstpage}-\pageref{lastpage}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{flushright}


    {\small
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{p{9cm}}
\textcolor{blue}{Заголовок}\\
Текст\\
\noindent \underline{Ключовые слова:} эволюционный оператор; КСО Волтерра; неподвижная точка; периодические точки.
\end{tabular}\end{center} }
\vspace{0.5 cm}
```

But Russian words change to question marks ????

?????????
?????
???????? ?????: ???????????? ????????; ??? ????????;
??????????? ?????; ????????????? ?????

How can I be read it in Russian?

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. How do you compile? You will need a font that contains Cyrillic characters. Compiling your code with pdflatex uses 'larm' legacy font, which contains Cyrillic. Compiling your code with xelatex with no font specified with `fontspec` uses the default `lmroman` font (Latin Modern), which has no Cyrillic, by definition.

Comment: You can put a `\fontname\font` command in your code, to see what the font is called.